# Shooting the enemy, how to calculate the next position of the projectile

Tags: c#, xna

I hava a Tower with the position Vector2 that shoots a target when i comes close enough. The projectile should inherit the tower's position as it's startposition and it then gets a target Vector2 that is suppose to hit.

How do I calulate this as i need to calulate the new position in every update when the projectile knows its own position and target position plus speed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have target and origin, then just doing target - origin gives you a new Vector2 which is the direction. You then need to normalize this direction vector, and multiply it by the projectile speed.

Pseudocode:

```
Vector2 target = objectToShootAt.position();
Vector2 origin = tower.position();
Vector2 direction = target - origin;

direction.normalize(); // or direction *= 1/direction.length()
direction *= speed;
```

Then just use direction and multiply it by the time between frames, and add this to the bullet position.

**Edit: to follow up on George's comment**
The pseudocode I showed will always miss the target if the target is moving since it assumes the bullet cannot curve and does not take into account target velocity. If the bullet curves, as George said, you need to recalculate the direction vector each frame.

To have a non curving bullet but that takes into account the target's velocity, you need to predict the target's position, which is done by estimating the position of the target based on its current heading, speed, and the time it will take for the bullet to get there.

Comment: Since he mentioned that he knows target position plus speed, it's worth mentioning that you'll need to recalculate this each frame (as the target will have moved on), or do some slightly more complex maths to calculate time of impact and adjust your target direction accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it will be easier to update bullet position by frame, but I was tried to solve the line equation from the tower to the expected position of the enemy.

```
  Equation from Enemy => Target = EnemyOrigin + EnemyDirection.Normalized * EnemySpeed * Time;

  Equation from Tower => Target = TowerOrigin + BulletDirection.Normalized * BulletSpeed * Time;

  Target = EO + ED * ES * T, Target = TO + BD * BS *T =>

                                               (EO - TO) + ED * ES * T 
=> EO + ED * ES * T = TO + BD * BS * T => BD = -----------------------
                                                        BS * T
```

Now we don't know Time, but we can aproximate it, (bullets will have different speed relative to distance):

```
Time = |(EnemyOrigen - TowerOrigen) / BulletSpeed| = |(EO - TO) / BS|;

         (EO  - TO )+ ED * ES * (EO - TO) / BS
=> BD = ---------------------------------------- =>   (+-1) * (One + (ED * ES) / BS);
                 BS * (EO - TO) / BS
```

Now we know the BulletDirection, the BulletOrigen and the Fly Time Duration, we only have to interpolate

BulletPos = TowerOrigin + BulletDirectionNormalized * BulletSpeed * TimeElapsedFromShot;

I have not tested it, and it maybe not a good solution.. but is only to show other alternative... ;)